# Using ggplot to plot more than 6 groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm aware this question has been asked before and have attempted to use the solutions in said posts but to no avail, and to avoid necro'ing old posts I thought I'd make a new one.

In my free time, which I have a lot of these days given the current pandemic, I've been watching episodes of Doctor Who and ranking them then plotting it in ggplot as a way to practice. It's been fun and I've learnt a lot.

The plot is a plot of rating (from 0 to 10) against episode number with the colour based on the incarnation of the doctor and the shape of the point based on the series. I've just reached series 7 and have hence run across the no more than 6 discrete values problem. I've tried using scale_shape_manual as suggested in other threads but this doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
#Load in dependencies
library(ggplot2)

#Initialise data
s1 = c(7.5,7,6,6,6.5,7.5,5.5,7,8,7,7.5,8.5)
s2 = c(6.5,6,7.5,7.5,8,7,7.5,5,7,8,3,2,8,8.5)
s3 = c(8,7,5,6,6,6.5,5.5,5.5,7,8,9.8,9,8.5,8)
s4 = c(7,8,8.5,8,7,7,7,7,9.5,9.5,9,9,8.5,8.5,6,8,9.5,9,9)
s5 = c(7,6,6.5,7.5,7,7,5.5,7.5,6.5,7,6,7.5,7,6)
s6 = c(6.5,7,5,8,7,7.5,7.5,5,8,6,7,5.5,5,6)
s7 = c(6,4,7.5,5,6.5,7)
s8 = c()
s9 = c()
s10 = c()
s11 = c()
s12 = c()

Doctor = seq(9,13,1)
Doc.all = c(rep.int(9, length(s1)), rep.int(10, length(s2)+length(s3)+length(s4)) , rep.int(11, length(s5) +length(s6)+length(s7)))#, rep.int(12, length(s8)+length(s9)+length(s10)), rep.int(13, length(s11)+length(s12))))
Series.all = c(rep.int(1, length(s1)), rep.int(2, length(s2)), rep.int(3,length(s3)), rep.int(4, length(s4)), rep.int(5, length(s5)), rep.int(6, length(s6)), rep.int(7,length(s7)))#, rep.int(12, length(s8)+length(s9)+length(s10)), rep.int(13, length(s11)+length(s12))))

#Analyse
Rating.all = c(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12) 

Season.mean = c(mean(s1),mean(s2),mean(s3),mean(s4),mean(s5),mean(s6),mean(s7),mean(s8),mean(s9),mean(s10),mean(s11),mean(s12))
Number.season = seq(1,12,1)

Number.Episodes = seq(1,length(s1)+length(s2)+length(s3)+length(s4)+length(s5)
                      +length(s6)+length(s7)+length(s8)+length(s9)+length(s10)
                      +length(s11)+length(s12),1)

#Plot all episodes on one plot
Data.All = data.frame(Rating.all, Number.Episodes, Doc.all, Series.all)
Doc.all.fac = factor(Data.All$Doc.all)
Series.fac = factor(Data.All$Series.all)

Breakdown.All = ggplot(Data.All, aes(x = Number.Episodes, y = Rating.all, color = Doc.all.fac, shape = Series.fac)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=(1:7)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Doctor") +
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, method = "loess", linetype = "dashed") +
  xlab("Episode Number") +
  ylab("Rating") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10), breaks = seq(0,10,1)) +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "Series")

print(Breakdown.All)
```

I apologize if it's messy/nonsensical/very inefficient, I'm just a student! The idea is that as I watch episodes I fill in the rating then I can source it and the plot will update with something a bit like this:
[Current plot of ratings including Series 7, displaying missing points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM0qf.png)

What am I doing wrong with scale_shape_manual? Is there an easier way to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `scale_shape_manual(values=(1:7))`which allows you to get 7 shapes and are then undoing it with `scale_shape_discrete`. What is the intention of using `scale_shape_discrete`?If it is label the shape column you can do this by `labs(shape="Series")`
An automated way to update the number of shapes in `scale_shape_manual` as you continue to add more series would be to `scale_shape_manual(values=1:uniqueN(Data.All$Series.all))`
uniqueN is the a data.table function that counts number of unique elements